# Can capacitors in speakers (Yamaha) be replaced by slightly different ones?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, speakers

[image: The red one]

Now, I know that people used replacement capacitors which has a Capacity of 22nF, 250V ac and 630V dc +/-5%

The Capacitor was labeled C515 on the board it is soldered on.

I was wondering how flexible those values are. Does it have to be 22nF and those exact voltages? People have been using overspeced ones but I'm kinda scared it will destroy even more.

I mean, best-case would be that some of you know the exact capacitor, but why not use one that is a bit different, if it works just as well?

How different can it be? I feel like the capacity has to be the same, but the voltage can be higher. Is there a limit to that though, where there is too little flow?

Comment: 630Vac is not overspec’d but you can use higher rating

Comment: Where is it in the circuit?  What job does it actually do?  The answers to those questions may dictate a more expensive X class or Y class capacitor that is guaranteed to fail a certain way that is different from the way that most other caps fail.

Comment: @AaronD i know none of those things. didn't turn on, build a thing that checks if anything is conductable, tested it on everything, the capacitor didn't work so i figured it was that

Comment: @MaritnGe So the cap might actually be good then.  They don't conduct DC at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any 22nF caps **as long as** they are made for 250VAC and 630VDC. You will never get the exact component, the important part is to match the specs of the original one.

Comment: So anything of 22nF >250Vac 630Vdc works?

Comment: @MaritnGe Close or slightly superior to the original specs, not inferior.

Comment: so not overkilling it with like 10000Vac or smth? like what is the tolerance? like 250Vac +5%?

Comment: @MaritnGe Something way to superior is indeed useless. A tolerance of ±5% is enough

Comment: but not +-5% but only +5% cause - would cause it to break earlier wouldn't it?

Comment: A capacitor or any passive component is always "±Value%", there is no "+5%" or "-5%". A 22nF 630V **is** what you need.

Comment: wait so can i meant the "tolerance" of the voltage. Like could i use one which has like <300VAC ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80446/discussion-between-dismantl-and-maritn-ge).

Comment: lacking the 20 karma needed to participate in chat. But thanks, so as close to the original one as possible. Got it, thanks C:

Comment: You might also mention X class and Y class caps, what's special about them, and why they absolutely must be what they are in certain situations.  There's not enough info yet to tell for sure if this is one of those situations, but given the voltage rating, it might be.